# Add "Minix" tag proposal

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

I asked a question ([Use Minix Filesystem on Ubuntu 13.04 (Kernel 3.8)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/311082/use-minix-filesystem-on-ubuntu-13-04-kernel-3-8)) concerning the Minix filesystem. Would it be a good idea for someone to add a "Minix" tag, or should we wait for more Minix-related topics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

done.

Comment: That was fast. Thank you.

Comment: I will accept the answer in five minutes (when SE will allow me).

Comment: @DevynCollierJohnson Would you mind editing it's  [tag wiki](http://askubuntu.com/tags/minix/info)? :)

Comment: Sure, I would love to.